# Prometheus get initial time of metric

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

How can I get initialization timestamp of metric from prometheus ?

I want to calculate the spent time between container creation and getting ready in kubernetes environment.

I can get creation time from **container_start_time_seconds**{namespace="mynamespace",pod="my-pod"}.
I think If I can get initialize time of **prober_probe_total**{namespace="mynamespace",pod="my-pod", probe_type="Readiness", result="successful"} metric, I can calculate the spent time of between container creation and getting ready, but I could not get this information with PromQL.

Comment: Welcome to the community! Which `prometheus` version is used? How was it deployed?

Comment: thank you @moonkotte, prometheus version is 2.26.1. I'm using openshift cluster and this prometheus is installed with openshift cluster.

Comment: Sorry for delay in answer, if you haven't tried it yet, consider asking this question in [Prometheus GitHub repo](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus) since developers and their community much more likely will help you to move forward.